# `method_missing': undefined method `has_paper_trail'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am upgrading my rails app from 5.1.4 to 5.2.0. I am getting the following error. I would appreciate any help debugging this. I have not put the entire stack trace below, please let me know if you need it.

I have paper_trail version 12.1.0 installed. Its odd though, I had been using ruby version 2.5.1 with rails version 5.1.4 and it never gave me errors. This error started only after I upgraded to rails 5.2.0

```
redd@tanya:~/galaxy$  rails s
[DEPRECATED] Bootsnap's `autoload_paths_cache:` option is deprecated and will be removed. If you use Zeitwerk this option is useless, and if you are still using the classic autoloader upgrading is recommended.
[DEPRECATED] Bootsnap's `disable_trace:` option is deprecated and will be removed. If you use Ruby 2.5 or newer this option is useless, if not upgrading is recommended.
DEPRECATION WARNING: The factory_girl gem is deprecated. Please upgrade to factory_bot. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v4.9.0/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md for further instructions. (called from <main> at /home/redd/galaxy/config/application.rb:9)
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.7 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
/home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.7/lib/active_record/type.rb:27: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.7/lib/active_record/type/adapter_specific_registry.rb:9: warning: The called method `add_modifier' is defined here
/home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.7/lib/active_model/type/integer.rb:13: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.7/lib/active_model/type/value.rb:8: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
/home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/specialized_string.rb:12: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.7/lib/active_model/type/value.rb:8: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    120: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    119: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    ....
      8: from /home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:661:in `new_constants_in'
      7: from /home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `block in load_file'
      6: from /home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
      5: from /home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
      4: from /home/redd/galaxy/app/models/users/user.rb:1:in `<main>'
      3: from /home/redd/galaxy/app/models/users/user.rb:2:in `<class:User>'
      2: from /home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.1.0/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:131:in `method_missing_with_attr_encrypted'
      1: from /home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.1.0/lib/attr_encrypted.rb:306:in `method_missing'
/home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.7/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `has_paper_trail' for #<Class:0x000055c56bb2be30> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  has_attached_file
```

Comment: `has_paper_trail` is a method that is provided by the [`paper_trail` gem](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail). Did you double-check if that gem is in your `Gemfile` and that you are using a version of that gem that supports Rails 5.2 (see a compatibility list in its [`README`](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail)).

Comment: @spickermann I have paper_trail version 12.1.0 installed. There's no compatibility list for rails in the readme you listed. Only for ruby. Its odd though, it says for version 12 you need ruby version 2.6.0 or greater but I had been using ruby version 2.5.1 with  rails version 5.1.4 and it never gave me errors. This error started only after I upgraded to 5.2.0

Comment: can you show a `app/models/users/user.rb` listing?

Comment: Have you tried `rails generate paper_trail:install`?

Answer (score -1):

1. Get the full stack trace (not the shortened version you listed above)
2. Find the lines containing `/home/redd/galaxy/config/initializers`
3. Insert the following code at the top of these files:

   ```
   # Loading `User` below would fail
   # if `User.has_paper_trail` is not loaded already
   require "paper_trail/frameworks/active_record"
   ```